# Element with multiple width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to give an object (for example a div or an img) multiple widths? So that the normal width of an object is 720 pixels, but when the screen size of the user is smaller than 720 pixels the element automatically change its width to 100%?

It would be nice if there would be a solution which only uses HTML, or CSS and wouldn't contain any JavaScript because I'm not really familiar with it. 
(But if JavaScript is the only way to achieve this, or it is really easy with JavaScript, please explain it like I'm 5)

Comment: Yes, look into the `max-width` css property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one possible way is to use `max-width` and `width`:

```
.foo {
  max-width: 720px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to have many different widths, according to different screen sizes, [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) are the way to go, as explained in another anwser.

Comment: It was so simple.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). These let you set different CSS for different screen sizes.

> Many media features are range features, which means they can be prefixed with "min-" or "max-" to express "minimum condition" or "maximum condition" constraints. For example, this CSS will apply styles only if your browser's viewport width is equal to or narrower than 12,450px:
>
> `@media (max-width: 12450px) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries

[Media Queries Demystified](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width)

Your CSS will look like:

```
.element {
    width: 75%;
}
@media screen and(max-width: 720px){
    .element{
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This sets the size of the element, and then says: if the screen is this width or smaller, do this.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can query the type and size of a screen using `@media` and various combinations of selectors and predicates. The following will provide a test that the medium is a screen (as opposed to print) and the maximum width of the screen is 720 pixels):

```
div {
    width: 720px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    div {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use multiple css in multiple size for example:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
   .item{
         width:100%;
        }
 }
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
   .item{
        width:80%;
        }
 }
```

or use free and complete and flexible framework for this purpose like

> Bootstrap
>
> Build responsive, mobile-first projects on the web with the world's
>   most popular front-end component library.
>
> Bootstrap is an open source toolkit for developing with HTML, CSS, and
>   JS. Quickly prototype your ideas or build your entire app with our
>   Sass variables and mixins, responsive grid system, extensive prebuilt
>   components, and powerful plugins built on jQuery.
>   [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)